Azure Portal: How to enable MFA? Do I need to purchase Entra ID Premium?
I received the following alert when I signed into the Azure portal:

I attempted to follow the steps it suggested, and ended up using entra.microsoft.com to attempt to set up a "conditional access policy."

But as you can see above, the button to create a new policy is disabled, and I seem to get a nudge to upgrade to Entra ID Premium. Is premium required to enable MFA? I'm just trying to be compliant with the upcoming change.
Thanks for any advice.
Adding for posterity:

My Azure subscription is connected not connected to an "organizational" account.
My own account does have MFA enabled. Was trying to understand what further action, if any, was being prompted by this message.


I enabled MFA for my Azure user by clicking "Add sign-in method" on https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info. I don't have Entra ID Premium.

Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to prevent me from logging in there with "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."

Maybe going to Entra ID > Users > your user > Authentication Methods would help? From here I clicked Access Panel Profile to get to the sign in methods page mentioned above.

Also if your user is an externally-federated account like a personal MS account, instead of one created from within Entra ID, you can add MFA methods on https://account.live.com/proofs/Manage/additional

Thanks again - it took me to the "myaccount" page. I should qualify that I already have MFA set up for my Microsoft account - I think the nudge it gave me is to make it a requirement for all users. (Sorry if my question was unclear)

Ah sorry, I made an assumption there. Yeah I think enforcing it early for all users might require Entra ID Premium before 10/15/2024.

AFAIK, enabling the MFA for individual users is a free feature in Azure Entra.
If you require more advanced MFA Capabilities such as

Conditional access
Risk based authentication
Phone based mfa (call/sms)
Authentication methods
monitoring and reporting
Advanced security

Then you need to consider purchasing Entra ID Premium.

No, you do not need to purchase premium.
Took me a while to find too, mainly because I was zoomed in and so the button was essentially off screen!
In Entra ID, go to Users:

Click the Per-user MFA button, which takes you here:

Select your user and click Enable MFA.
Done :)
